# Defining strict application ($!) myself does not result in the same performance

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm reading [this blog post by Michael Snoyman](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/09/all-about-strictness) recently. In an exercise suggested there, I tried to define `$!` operator by myself:

```
import Prelude hiding ( ($!) )

($!) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($!) f x = x `seq` f x

mysum :: [Int] -> Int
mysum list0 =
  go list0 0
  where
    go [] total = total
    go (x:xs) total = go xs $! total + x

main = print $ mysum [1..1000000]
```

I thought this works well, though the usage of memory was terrible. My first question is this. Why didn't this work well?

Then, I checked its definition in Prelude. It reads:

```
($!)                    :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $! x                  = let !vx = x in f vx  -- see #2273
```

So, I copied it into my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Prelude hiding ( ($!) )

($!) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($!) f x =
  let !vx = x
   in f vx

mysum :: [Int] -> Int
mysum list0 =
  go list0 0
  where
    go [] total = total
    go (x:xs) total = go xs $! total + x

main = print $ mysum [1..1000000]
```

and the result was:

```
Linking mysum4 ...
500000500000
     209,344,064 bytes allocated in the heap
     130,602,696 bytes copied during GC
      54,339,936 bytes maximum residency (8 sample(s))
          66,624 bytes maximum slop
              80 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

You can see how terrible this is compared to the result of using Prelude's `$!` operator:

```
Linking mysum4 ...
500000500000
     152,051,776 bytes allocated in the heap
          41,752 bytes copied during GC
          44,384 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
          21,152 bytes maximum slop
               1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)
```

My second question is where did this difference come from?

Furthermore, I think it can be re-written like this:

```
($!) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $! !x = f x
```

Is there any reason not to do this? This is my third question.

Answer (score 26):

*Aha!*  It's a precedence issue.  You forgot to paste the line:

```
infixr 0  $!
```

and so when you use your own version, it gets parsed as

```
go (x:xs) total = (go xs $! total) + x
```

which obviously has terrible performance.  It's almost a coincidence that it even gives you the right answer.

Comment: You say "almost a coincidence"; why "almost"?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Just hedging so I don't get a comment like well *actually*, since + is commutative and asso...

Comment: But that comment would be informative. Could you provide it please? 